Problems with Databricks Unity Catalog - Catalog Explorer not loading
Can someone let me know if there are nationwide issues with Databricks Unity Catalog. My Catalog Explore won't load


We are not seeing any issues. Please ensure that the computing clusters being used here are up and running
